# Getting a “FIND: Parameter format not correct in make” when trying to build a repository from source code

Tags: powershell, find

I'm trying to build a repository from source using GNU `make` but this line of code

```
src_js := $(shell find src -name '*.js')
```

gives the error:

```
FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

What is the mistake here? Sorry if this has been asked before but I'm not familiar with shell scripts at all. I'm using Windows, if that helps.

Comment: What repo are you cloning and attempting to compile?

Comment: make is finding the command version of find not the unix version. You should be running make in a bash shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `src` is the name of an existing directory in the "current" directory, your find command looks OK for Unix or Linux. But in MS-DOS, the `FIND` command is used to search through text files, not through directories.

To get the correct parameters for a find, try this in a DOSBox:

```
FIND /?
```

But they are probably useless to you. You may have more luck with the `DIR` command, as in:

```
DIR /S /B  src/*.js
```

Comment: If the original poster is using a canned `make` script how can they do what you describe? Seems to men they cloned a repo from somewhere and are following provided instructions and getting nowhere.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I'm just answering his question, I didn't intend to answer yours.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, dir /s /b src\\*.js worked for me but I'm encountering other errors unrelated to this down the line, I'll create an issue on the repo.

Comment: Then perhaps you could accept the answer?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Honestly, my question is simply asking you to put context top all of this. This is not just a random question about FIND but rather something that has context. The most likely core issue is that the Windows command line `FIND` is what is being called but the source file is intending to us the Linux/Unix version of `find` as [David Postil explains in his comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1600967/getting-a-find-parameter-format-not-correct-in-make-when-trying-to-build-a-re/1600996?noredirect=1#comment2440355_1600967).

Comment: @Giacomo1968.  OK, but have another look at my answer.  You took the time to edit it, but not to read it?  All that context is there.  I knew what the issue was just by seeing "FIND:".  The OP may have more questions, help him with those.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Tone it down please. I made a mistake. And a lot of times when edits Arte made — not just by me, but others — the goal is to clean up content but not necessarily read content and meaning. This is not an aberration. That is what copy editing is about.

Comment: @Giacomo1968. No problem.  I'm sure you didn't get your reputation by editing.  Keep it up.